# Customize SharePoint:FormFields to a specific height

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I'm customizing a NewForm.aspx page and I've created a few new SharePoint:FormFields in the form of textboxes. I'm looking to customize the height of these boxes on a case-by-case basis, but I can't figure it out.

I've looked into DisplaySize, but that only controls the width of a specific textboxe, and I've seen adding in:

`<style>
.ms-long{width:100px;}
</style>`

but that changes every SharePoint:FormField size, not just one.

Answer (score 1):

Find the element in the complete html output, and use the id rather than the class as the css selector. If you can't find a suitable selector or you need to use selectors not supported in ie, you can use javascript/jquery to find and modify individual controls.

Answer (score 0):

If you are customizing the NewForm.aspx, and you want to customize the look of the controls, you should also customize the CSS by using your own .css file. That may or may not include a customized master page.

Answer (score 0):

I take it your a user of SharePoint Designer to be editing NewForm.aspx. Personally the route I would go down is to design a custom text box field and give it the desired size that way. Might not be what you want, but it's one way to do it.